# Changing multiple physicals paths in IIS

Tags: iis-7, scripting

My site has been moved to a new location, and now i have to change thousands of physical paths of sub-sites.

The old location was:

```
D:\blabla\MySite
```

And the new location is:

```
\\Server\MySharedFolder\MySite
```

Now i need to replace the string "D:\" with "\Server\MySharedFolder\" in the physical path of thousands of sub-sites in IIS.

What is the most recommended way to do so?

Comment: do you mean in your IIS, all setting with absolute path, not relative  path? Can you give some samples in your setting file?

Comment: Now all of the settings are pointing to: "D:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite", and i want to they be pointed to "\\Server\MySharedFolder\MySite".